# how to define struct inside of class?

Tags: c++

I have trouble compiling the code at the bottom. I do this in `C` all the time but can't do it in `C++` when it's inside a class. Could someone enlighten me what is wrong here?

```
class Parser {

  struct table {
     string first;
     string second;
     string third;
  } c_table [] = {
   "0","a","b",
   "0","c","d",
   "0","e","f",
  };
};

int main() {

  return 0;
}

test.cpp:22:3: error: too many initializers for ‘Parser::table [0]’
test.cpp:22:3: error: could not convert ‘(const char*)"0"’ from ‘const char*’ to ‘Parser::table’
test.cpp:22:3: error: could not convert ‘(const char*)"a"’ from ‘const char*’ to ‘Parser::table’
test.cpp:22:3: error: could not convert ‘(const char*)"b"’ from ‘const char*’ to ‘Parser::table’
test.cpp:22:3: error: could not convert ‘(const char*)"0"’ from ‘const char*’ to ‘Parser::table’
test.cpp:22:3: error: could not convert ‘(const char*)"c"’ from ‘const char*’ to ‘Parser::table’
test.cpp:22:3: error: could not convert ‘(const char*)"d"’ from ‘const char*’ to ‘Parser::table’
test.cpp:22:3: error: could not convert ‘(const char*)"0"’ from ‘const char*’ to ‘Parser::table’
test.cpp:22:3: error: could not convert ‘(const char*)"e"’ from ‘const char*’ to ‘Parser::table’
test.cpp:22:3: error: could not convert ‘(const char*)"f"’ from ‘const char*’ to ‘Parser::table’
```

Comment: Trouble compiling means you should include the full error.

Comment: @chris: I have included error

Comment: this has **nothing** to do with classes.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish here?

Comment: @KarolyHorvath I think it does, a wee bit :) You need to specify the dimension whereas you could omit it if the array had local scope.

Comment: just add curly braces around structure initializers

Comment: @jrok: that's interesting. is there a difference? the compiler can figure out the size....

Comment: First declare `struct`, then define an array member for it. Or do what @jrok suggests. That looks to be some smelly [tag:c]-style somehow anyway ...

Comment: @KarolyHorvath See the last paragraph in my answer. I can't find the standardese for this at the moment, though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pre-C++11 you're not allowed to initialize members inside class definition (except for `static const` members of integral types). This leaves you no other choice but to fill it inside a body of a constructor.

In C++11, you can have an initializer, but

- you need to add another set of braces for each array element and
- you need to specify the size of the array

---

```
#include <string>
using std::string;

class Parser {

  struct table {
     string first;
     string second;
     string third;
  } c_table [3] = {
   {"0","a","b"}, // <-- note the braces
   {"0","c","d"},
   {"0","e","f"}
  };
};
```

[**Live Example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d4af6d70313ebeaf)

I think the reason you need to specify the dimension is because the initializer from the class definition can be trumped over by a member initializer inside some constructor, which could have a different element count.